# Node.js express js serving static files is very slow on bigger files

Tags: node.js, express, http, static, ejs

I am trying to serve static files with express.static but on files that are 1MB - 5MB it seems to take for ages to load. As you can see I am already adding the static middleware as first one.

```
const app       = express();
app.use("/", express.static("./Client/Static"));

const httpServer    = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(Config["http-port"], () => console.log("STARTED HTTP SERVER ON " + Config["http-port"]));

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "Client/Views"));
app.engine("html", ejs.renderFile);
app.set("view engine", "html");

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bbBodyParser({
    "limit": "6mb"
}));
```

Result, when reloading without cache (The file is so big because its the entire Font Awesome Library):

[image: Network]

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with express.js because I just hosted them straight on IIS windows server and its still loading very slow

Answer (score 0):

there's an issue for this situation, i guess you can find the solution here

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/321

but in a production enviroment it's better use cdn like s3 or other you may like.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to find the buffer size option anywhere in the documentation, In addition, in their code on github there is nothing with buffer size